# How to compare time greater than 3 sec in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, time

How to compare time is greater than 3 sec in ios. 
Time is like "2016-05-10 05:31:14". I got code for comparing like greater or less with specific time but how i will achieve it is greater than 3 sec etc.

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` + `timeIntervalSinceDate`?

Comment: What do you mean by "greater than 3 sec"? Are you trying to compare two `NSDates`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one. May be Its possible for you:

```
NSDate* timeNow = [NSDate date];

// If less than 30 seconds, do something
if ([timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:anEarlierTime] < 30.0f)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: My time is like 2016-05-10 05:31:14 and timeNow is like 2016-05-10 10:23:23 +0000. Is it ok ?

Comment: yes, Its ok. If any issue in Date time format please use NSDateformater

Comment: did you got you solution?

Comment: [timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:anEarlierTime]= nan

Comment: please uss this code for convert date format:------> NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];NSString *strDate = [myTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
    NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];

Comment: No , i have converted given time in UTC as well so no need to replace. Some time getting timeIntervalSinceDate:anEarlierTime]=15381.820623

Comment: you need to convert "My time 2016-05-10 05:31:14" date

Comment: NSDate* timeNow = [NSDate date];
         
         NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
         [df setTimeZone:timeZone];
         [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
         NSDate *messageDate = [df dateFromString: sender_time];
         
         
         
         NSLog(@"timediff=%f",[timeNow timeIntervalSinceDate:messageDate]);

Comment: please tell me what is sender_time?

Comment: Now it is working. sender_time was som etime @"" so i was getting nan.Now i resolved nan issue and getting time like 14624.537369 and 14624.537369>3.0f condition is working now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111535/discussion-between-djtiwari-and-vijay-kachhadiya).

Comment: When i am converting string into Nsdate then some times getting null

Comment: NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
             [df setTimeZone:timeZone];
             [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
             NSDate *timeOld = [df dateFromString: old_time];

Comment: please covert it in time format. both date convert in time format

Comment: Please try this one :------>    
    NSDate* timeNow = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setTimeZone:timeZone];
        [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *mytime = [df stringFromDate:timeNow];
    NSDate *mydate = [df dateFromString:mytime];
     NSDate *messageDate = [df dateFromString: @"2016-05-10 06:31:14"]; NSLog(@"timediff=%f",[mydate timeIntervalSinceDate:messageDate]/(3600));

Answer (score 1):

You can get seconds difference between two dates by

```
NSDate *someDate;//Some Date

NSLog(@"Seconds --> %f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: someDate]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)isEndDateIsSmallerThanCurrent:(NSDate *)checkEndDate
{
NSDate* enddate = checkEndDate;
NSDate* currentdate = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [enddate timeIntervalSinceDate:currentdate];
double secondsInMinute = 60;

// secondsBetweenDates is your seconds difference
NSInteger secondsBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInMinute;

if (secondsBetweenDates == 0)
    return YES;
else if (secondsBetweenDates < 0)
    return YES;
else
    return NO;
}
```

Here, secondsBetweenDates is your difference in seconds. You can check that it is smaller or greater or equal than 3.

You can get difference here in hours also!

Hope this will help :)